# Looking for a better way to time my animation in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

As a beginner project I'm making a flash card app for my kids. When they get a correct answer a random emoji and phrase appear briefly on the screen. I want it to be quick, about 1 second. I have a trigger boolean that launches the animation and then when the trigger is set to false the animation disappears. The if trigger code is in my composable where I want my animation to show.

I've tried using launcheffect with a 1000ms delay but the screen is recomposed and the launcheffect is cancelled before the animation shows. The code I've posted works as desired but I feel there is a way to use a coroutine instead of Handler for the 1 second delay. If I use delay inside the Disposable Effect it says it should only be called from a coroutine or another suspend function.

```kotlin
if (trigger) {
    AnimalEmojiAnimation(emoji = Emoji.getEmoji(), phrase = Emoji.getPhrase())
}

@Composable
fun Calculate(viewModel: HomeViewModel, navController: NavController) {
    val operation: Operation = when (viewModel.text.signText.value) {
        "+" -> Addition()
        "-" -> Subtraction()
        "x" -> Multiplication()
        "÷" -> Division()
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid operation")
    }

    val answer = operation.perform(viewModel.text.topText.value, viewModel.text.bottomText.value)

    when {
        viewModel.text.text.value.isNotEmpty() -> {
            when (answer) {
                (viewModel.text.text.value.toInt()) -> {

                    viewModel.triggerEmojiAnimation.value = true

                    DisposableEffect(viewModel.triggerEmojiAnimation.value) {
                        onDispose {
                            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({                        viewModel.triggerEmojiAnimation.value = false}, 1000)
                        }
                    }

                    PlaySound(isCorrect = true)
                    viewModel.text.text.value = ""
                    viewModel.answer.count.value = viewModel.answer.count.value + 1

                    when {
                        viewModel.answer.correctFirstTime.value -> {
                            viewModel.answer.countCorrect.value++
                            GenProblems(viewModel, navController)
                        } else -> {
                        GenProblems(viewModel, navController)
                    }
                    }
                } else -> {
                PlaySound(isCorrect = false)
                viewModel.answer.correctFirstTime.value = false
            }
            }
        } else -> PlaySound(isCorrect = false)
    }
}
```